Show an activity while the phone is lock in Android app
I am trying to show an activity when the app receives an specific message from a bluetooth device even if the phone is locked. I have already have the activity and the connection part and also it works when I lock the phone with the app open. However, when for example I am in the Menu, I lock the phone and the app is working on the background, the phone doesn't turn on and the activity only starts when I unlock the phone and open again the app. In that case I don't know how can I bring the activity to the top, do I need another FLAGs or change the functions?.
Here is my code:
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_call);

        Window window = getWindow();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            setShowWhenLocked(true);
            setTurnScreenOn(true);
        } else {
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
        }

        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);

        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        if (powerManager != null) {
            wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(
                    PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP,
                    "MyApp::MyWakelockTag"
            );
            wakeLock.acquire(10 * 60 * 1000L /* 10 minutos */);

            Intent foregroundIntent = new Intent(CallActivity.this, CallActivity.class);
            foregroundIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(foregroundIntent);

            wakeLock.release();

        }


I also tried to use the KeyguardManagar but it doesn't change anything. I think the problem is that the app is in the background, because as I said, when I lock the phone when the app is open the code works. Also tried to correct the Version issues that I initially had but maybe there is something I am missing?.
